# terraform output of all external ips of a vm target pool or backend service pool

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have VMs terraformed and managed in an gcp/gce `google_compute_target_pool` by a `google_compute_region_instance_group_manager`

```
resource "google_compute_target_pool" "my-target-pool" {
  name             = "${local.pre}-my-target-pool"
}

data "google_compute_region_instance_group" "my-group_data" {
  self_link = "${google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.my-group-manager.instance_group}"
}
```

now I want to `output` all external IPs which each instance has (and they have an external IP I checked on that!)

I tried several things, but none of them works, as terraform always complaints that some object does not have such an attribute.

here some tries:

```
output jumpbox_ip {
  # value = "${google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.my-group-manager.instance_group.instances.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip}"
  # value = "${google_compute_region_instance_group.my-group_data.instances.*....
  value = "${google_compute_target_pool.my-target-pool.instances.*....}"
}
```

how can I output a list of all IPs of all VMs in a target-pool (or backend-service in case of an internal LB?

Comment: I do not see ip address as an exportable attribute for either the resource or the data according to the documentation. You may not be able to do this natively.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try a `google_compute_instance` data resource per each instance:

```
data "google_compute_instance" "instances" {
  count = "${length(data.google_compute_region_instance_group.my-group_data.instances)}"

  name = "${data.google_compute_region_instance_group.my-group_data.instances[count.index]}"
}

output "instance_ids" {
  value = "${data.google_compute_instance.instances.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip }"
}
```

Comment: well `"google_compute_region_instance_group_manager"` uses a `"google_compute_instance_template"` to instantiate these to a `"google_compute_region_backend_service"` ... question would be how to get the `"google_computer_instance"`s out of that `"google_compute_region_backend_service"` !?